# Which IPs can I use which will not conflict with local host machine networks?

Tags: networking, vagrant

My dev machine is a laptop and runs multiple Vagrant VMs. I have config like this in my Vagrantfile

```
s.vm.network "private_network", ip: "10.0.0.4"
```

Then in my host machine's /etc/hosts, I have

```
10.0.0.4  mymachine
```

This usually works well because my host machine is on local networks which use 192.168.0.0–192.168.255.255.

My host machine is a laptop which I take to a variety of different locations with different network configurations. My host machine is currently on a network in an office which uses 10.0.0.0–10.255.255.255, and vagrant is giving me this message:

> The specified host network collides with a non-hostonly network! This
>   will cause your specified IP to be inaccessible. Please change the IP
>   or name of your host only network so that it no longer matches that of
>   a bridged or non-hostonly network.

I could switch all my machine's to use 192.168.0.x, but this is not ideal because:

- I'd have to update /etc/hosts
- I'll have the same problem on other networks
- I'll have to education the other developers on how to deal with this sort of thing

Is there any way around this? Can I tell Vagrant to allow the possible collision, or somehow make a sub-network that isn't effected by the conflict?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check the [IANA IPv4 Special-Purpose Address Registry](https://www.iana.org/assignments/iana-ipv4-special-registry/iana-ipv4-special-registry.xhtml) and [IANA IPv6 Special-Purpose Address Registry](https://www.iana.org/assignments/iana-ipv6-special-registry/iana-ipv6-special-registry.xhtml) for suitable address ranges whic can be routed but not globally routed.

For instance: IPv4 has the `Documentation (TEST-NET-1)` range of `192.0.2.0/24`, and IPv6 has the `Unique-Local` range of `fc00::/7`.

The IPv6 `Unique-Local` range has a few caveats. The lower half of the range, `fc00::/8`, is reserved for assignment by a global authority, but you can use the upper half of the range, `fd00::/8`, if you use a compliant random number generator to choose the next 40 bits (Global ID) to try to be globally unique.

Comment: using "192.0.2.x" seems to be working perfectly on all networks, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Given the current elements from your question:

- if your office network uses range `10.0.0.0 – 10.255.255.255`,
- you do not want to use `192.168.0.0/16`

Then the only private network range left you can use is `172.16.0.0 – 172.31.255.255` (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network#Private_IPv4_address_spaces)

If you try to comply with all the possible networks you will not be able to get a single IP.

> I'd have to update /etc/hosts

You can use the [hostmanager](https://github.com/devopsgroup-io/vagrant-hostmanager) plugin which update the file for you (It can update for both the host and the guest machine) so if you need to change network, on `vagrant up` the file will be updated accordingly

Comment: I'm running the machine's on a laptop which will be on a variety of networks. I'll clarify the question.

Comment: And if you go to an office that uses 172.xxx you are hosed again.

Comment: I dont think you can find 1 IP that will be good for you then - There will always be cases where you have conflict with existing network - adding suggestion to use plugin then